# What is the difference between the ARRAffinity and ARRAffinitySameSite cookies for Azure?

Tags: azure, session, azure-web-app-service, load-balancing

When ARRAffinity enabled I get two cookies: `ARRAffinity` and `ARRAffinitySameSite` both with the same value.

What is the difference between these two cookies?

I'm trying to figure out some more advanced scenarios by deleting the cookies manually after a while, to prevent users that never closes their tabs to starve a single instance because they never stick.

I need the stickyness because I'm making extensive use of memory cache and I want to make the chance as high as possible for a cache hit.

(I don't want to use the extra hop for a distributed cache)

Comment: Possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73542435/258510