# What is the ARRAffinitySameSite cookie for?

Tags: azure, cookies, azure-web-app-service, arr

I'm calling an Azure app service app and found these two cookies:

[image]

I understand the `ARRAffinity` cookie is to make sure the request is always sent back to the same backend instance, but what is the `ARRAffinitySameSite` cookie for?

Comment: `ARRAffinitySameSite` is for Azure Web Sites for load balancing our application and ensures that, during any browsing session, the visitor's page requests are forwarded to the same server.

Comment: @HarshithaV Then what's the `ARRAffinity` cookie for?

Comment: Please refer [ARRAffinity](https://appserviceblog.com/en/arr-affinity-azure-app-services/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of `ARRAffinitySameSite` and `ARRAffinity` cookies is the same - they help to direct requests to the correct instance in load-balanced environments.

The only difference between them is the `SameSite` attribute. `ARRAffinitySameSite` was introduced when [Chromium-based browsers enforced the new SameSite policy in 2020](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/).
However, some [old browsers](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients/) do not support the `SameSite` attribute and Azure keeps the cookie `ARRAffinity` for backward compatibility.

Comment: I thought if something is not supported, it's just ignored. Couldn't it just use the one cookie with the SameSite attribute, and it'd just ignore it if it's not supported?

Comment: Azure can't tell old browsers to ignore the SameSite attribute. For instance, Chrome versions 51-66 and similar Chromium-based browsers reject cookies with `SameSite=None` which was correct according to the cookie specification at that time. If Azure did not keep the original `ARRAffinity` cookie, then sticky sessions would not work for these browsers and requests could go to any instance in the cluster.